# How do I achieve the functionality of an indirect formula, when referencing closed workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sharepoint

I have a dashboard report which pulls data from multiple other workbooks, it pulls data for the current month, prior month and prior prior month. I had started building it using an INDIRECT formula embedded in a VLOOKUP, so that you could change the date of the current month and that would build a filepath for the VLOOKUP, e.g.

[https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/[YEAR]/[MONTH]/Source](https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/%5BYEAR%5D/%5BMONTH%5D/Source) file/Tab name

[] being the dynamic elements of the formula.

I wouldn't say I am confident with VBA, but I am wondering if this is a better way to achieve the result? The formula works fine but only if all 3 source files are open.

The INDIRECT formulas work absolutely fine when the workbooks are open, however I need them to work when the other files are closed.

The intention is that the dashboard file is as automated as possible. The data processing team would update the source files as normal (part of their role and used for other purposes) but the user of the dashboard should only really have to change the dates and everything else should update dynamically.

Comment: `INDIRECT` function is designed to work only with open Workbooks. So you will have to directly reference these workbooks through your formulas.

Comment: Power Query will pull the data you need.  You could connect it up to a cell on your worksheet so it pulls the correct month.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Interesting, never used Power Query before, thanks - will take a look!

Comment: Without adding as a full answer you can create a query I've called fParameter which will pull back the info from a specified row in a table on your worksheet:  `let Parameter=(TableName,RowNumber) => let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],value = Source{RowNumber-1}[Value] in value in Parameter`  Your table must have the header `Value` as used in the code - `[Value]`.

Comment: You can then use that function to pull data from an Excel file specified in the table:  `let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Text.From(fParameter("Table1",1))),null, true), TargetSheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data] in TargetSheet`.  This pulls from the first row in a table called `Table1` and looks at `Sheet1`.